# Python-Kivy: Change screens using Python method (nested Screen managers created in Kivy code)

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am new-ish to Kivy, but have created an inventory program using Tkinter.

I am making an Inventory Program using Kivy and plan on having a login screen first with a TextInput box for the username (only), and with the on_text_verify I would like it eventually to run a method that checks the username against a database, but for now I am trying just to get it to run a method (in Python code) that changes the screen to one which contains a nested ScreenManager.

I know how to use KV code to make it change screens, but since I will need to check the username against a database I will need it to instead run a Python method which does so and then, if the username is accepted, then change the screen. Here is what I have so far:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
## I have imported all of these as I have been trying out different things ##

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass
class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass
class ScanScreen(Screen):
    pass
class InventoryScreen(Screen):
    pass
class ItemsScreen(Screen):
    pass
class LogsScreen(Screen):
    pass
class AlertsScreen(Screen):
    pass
class HelpScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MainWindow(FloatLayout):


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def goto_Mainscr(self):
        self.current="Mainscr"


class Invtest3App(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Invtest3App().run()
```

Here is the KV code:

```
<MainWindow>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    name: "mainw"
    id: mw
    ScreenManager:
        id: loginsm
        LoginScreen:
        MainScreen:

<ScanScreen>:
    name: "Scan"
    Button:
        text: "Scan In"
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, 'y': 0}
        size_hint: 1.0/5.0, 0.1
    Button:
        text: "Scan Out"
        pos_hint: {"x": 1.0/5.0, 'y': 0}
        size_hint: 1.0/5.0, 0.1
    Button:
        text: "Event"
        pos_hint: {"x": 2.0/5.0, 'y': 0}
        size_hint: 1.0/5.0, 0.1
    Button:
        text: "Recount"
        pos_hint: {"x": 3.0/5.0, 'y': 0}
        size_hint: 1.0/5.0, 0.1
    Button:
        text: "Logout"
        pos_hint: {"x": 4.0/5.0, 'y': 0}
        size_hint: 1.0/5.0, 0.1
        on_press: app.root.ids.loginsm.current = 'Loginscr'

<InventoryScreen>:
    name: "Inventory"
    Label:
        text: "Inventory Screen"

<ItemsScreen>:
    name: "Items"
    Label:
        text: "Items Screen"

<LogsScreen>:
    name: "Logs"
    Label:
        text: "Logs Screen"

<AlertsScreen>:
    name: "Alerts"
    Label:
        text: "Alerts Screen"

<HelpScreen>:
    name: "Help"
    Label:
        text: "Help Screen"

<LoginScreen>:
    name: "Loginscr"
    id: loginscr
    Label:
        name: "loginlabel"
        text: "Scan ID Barcode or Enter V# and Press Enter"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    TextInput:
        hint_text: "Scan ID Barcode or Enter V# and Press Enter"
        id: login_input
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.2}
        multiline: False
        focus: True
        on_text_validate: app.root.goto_Mainscr; self.text=""
        #app.root.goto_Mainscr
        #app.root.ids.loginsm.current = "Mainscr"

<MainScreen>:
    name: "Mainscr"
    FloatLayout:
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
        Button:
            name: "scanButton"
            text: "Scan"
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
            size_hint: 1.0/6.0, 1
            on_press: root.ids.sm.current = "Scan"
        Button:
            name: "inventoryButton"
            text: "Inventory"
            pos_hint: {'x': 1.0/6.0, 'y': 0}
            size_hint: 1.0/6.0, 1
            on_press: root.ids.sm.current = "Inventory"
        Button:
            name: "itemsButton"
            text: "Items"
            pos_hint: {'x': 2.0/6.0, 'y': 0}
            size_hint: 1.0/6.0, 1
            on_press: root.ids.sm.current = "Items"
        Button:
            name: "logsButton"
            text: "Logs"
            pos_hint: {'x': 3.0/6.0, 'y': 0}
            size_hint: 1.0/6.0, 1
            on_press: root.ids.sm.current = "Logs"
        Button:
            name: "alertsButton"
            text: "Alerts"
            pos_hint: {'x': 4.0/6.0, 'y': 0}
            size_hint: 1.0/6.0, 1
            on_press: root.ids.sm.current = "Alerts"
        Button:
            name: "helpButton"
            text: "Help"
            pos_hint: {'x': 5.0/6.0, 'y': 0}
            size_hint: 1.0/6.0, 1
            on_press: root.ids.sm.current = "Help"
    FloatLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            id: sm
            pos_hint: {'top': 0.9}
            size_hint: 1, 0.9
            ScanScreen:
            InventoryScreen:
            ItemsScreen:
            LogsScreen:
            AlertsScreen:
            HelpScreen:
```

Comment: I understand your question which is why this isn't an answer. I just want to point out that you can do what you're attempting to do inside the .kv and still call straight python functions.

Comment: I suppose the issue is with calling a python function from kv. Every time I call a function that changes screens, nothing happens. In the future this same function will first check the username against a mysql database, and if validated, then switch screens, but FIRST I need to at least get it to switch screens, or ANYTHING AT ALL. thanks!

Comment: So you can switch screens with straight python while using  .kv but it's dirty. The way you've got it set now is the best way, to do it while using .kv If your long run goal is to get the username and verify it, and then switch your screen. What you could do is just throw a bool variable inside the .kv set it as false and when the user inputs the username assuming it's correct you could then switch the flag to true and change the screen. How? Do it on your call to verify the text. For instance in the on_text_validate(). Otherwise, if you want to drop the .kv language see the answer from @Qback

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manage screens without using kv then it looks like this:

1. Import needed classes:

   ```
   from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
   ```
2. Create a screen manager variable:

   ```
   scene=ScreenManager()
   ```
3. Create a screen:

   ```
   screen=Screen(name="login_screen")
   ```
4. Create second screen:

   ```
   second_screen=Screen(name="main_screen")
   ```

Now you can change screens like this:

```
scene.current="login_screen"
scene.current="main_screen"
```

And you can add widgets to those screens.

Comment: Thanks, but I know this already. I would prefer to use Python AND KV if possible. I would mainly like to use Python code for the functions/logic, and KV for displaying everything.